# Aggregate/Group_by second minimum value in R

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by

I have used either `group_by()` in `dplyr` or the `aggregate()` function to aggregate across columns in `R`. For my current problem I want to group by an individual but finding the second lowest of one column (Number) and the lowest of another (Year). So, if my data looks like this:

```
Number     Individual     Year     Value
123        M. Smith       2010     234
435        M. Smith       2011     346
435        M. Smith       2012     356
524        M. Smith       2015     432
119        J. Jones       2010     345
119        J. Jones       2012     432
254        J. Jones       2013     453
876        J. Jones       2014     654
```

I want it to become:

```
Number     Individual     Year     Value
435        M. Smith       2011     346
254        J. Jones       2013     453
```

Thank you.

Comment: Not clear to me. Second lowest of which column and lowest of which ?

Comment: @RonakShah sorry, edited to show this.

Comment: This looks to me like one is second to _lowest_ while the other is second to _highest_.  Sadly, my R isn't strong enough to answer either or your questions :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use the `dplyr` package. `dt2` is the final output. The idea is to filter out the minimum in the `Number` column, then arrange the data frame by `Individual`, `Number`, and `Year`. Finally, select the first row of each group.

```
# Load package
library(dplyr)

# Create example data frame
dt <- read.table(text = "Number     Individual     Year     Value
123        'M. Smith'       2010     234
                 435        'M. Smith'       2011     346
                 435        'M. Smith'       2012     356
                 524        'M. Smith'       2015     432
                 119        'J. Jones'       2010     345
                 119        'J. Jones'       2012     432
                 254        'J. Jones'       2013     453
                 876        'J. Jones'       2014     654",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Process the data
dt2 <- dt %>%
  group_by(Individual) %>%
  filter(Number != min(Number)) %>%
  arrange(Individual, Number, Year) %>%
  slice(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(Individual) %>%
    arrange(Individual, Number) %>%
    filter(Number != max(Number)) %>%
    slice(which.max(Number))
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   Individual [2]
#  Number Individual  Year Value
#   <int>      <chr> <int> <int>
#1    254   J. Jones  2013   453
#2    435   M. Smith  2011   346
```